# How can I make these horizontal zigzags go in the vertical direction in the turtle python sandbox?

Tags: python-turtle

I got placed in a coding class and I have no idea what I'm doing.
This is supposed to create a nametag for a project that I have to finish by tonight.
Please help me figure out how to make the horizontal zigzags vertical.

```
t.pensize(24)

def zig_zag_line(num_zig_zags):
  zig_zag = 0
  t.setheading(20)
  while zig_zag < num_zig_zags:
    t.forward(40)
    t.right(40)
    t.forward(40)
    t.left(40)
    zig_zag = zig_zag + 1

def write_name(id_name):
  style = ('Times New Roman', 70, 'bold')
  t.write(id_name, font=style, align='center')

def white_space():
  t.color("white")
  t.pensize(26)
  for i in range(3):
    t.pu()
    t.goto(-260, i * 30)
    t.pd()
    zig_zag_line(7)
    i = i + 30

color1 = input("What is color 1?: ")
color2 = input("What is color 2?: ")
color3 = input("What is color 3?: ")

for i in range(-30, 33, 3):
  if i % 9 == 0:
    t.color(color1)
  elif i % 9 == 3:
    t.color(color2)
  else:
    t.color(color3)
  t.pu()
  t.goto(-260, i * 10)
  t.pd()
  zig_zag_line(7)

white_space()
t.color("black")
t.pu()
t.goto(0, 5)
t.pd()
write_name("")
t.hideturtle()
```

I just want to change the direction in which the zigzags are going. If anyone knows how to help I would really appreciate because I know virtually nothing about how to code this. I've been trying to figure it out but I'm going solely off the notes I've taken in class and I can't seem to figure out just how to make it go from horizontal to vertical.

Comment: Use t.setheading(90)

Comment: here is the link to the site: https://www.pythonsandbox.com/turtle please help me finish this.

Comment: SO is only a help and suggestion site. its not a good idea to ask others to finish your work/project.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things we need to do: first swap our sense of x and y:

```
t.goto(-260, i * 10)
```

becomes:

```
t.goto(i * 10, -260)
```

and change our initial heading:

```
t.setheading(20)
```

becomes:

```
t.setheading(20 + 90)
```

A rework of the zigzag lines part of your code to make them vertical:

```
import turtle as t

def zig_zag_line(num_zig_zags):
    t.setheading(110)

    for _ in range(num_zig_zags):
        t.forward(40)
        t.right(40)
        t.forward(40)
        t.left(40)

color1 = input("What is color 1? ")
color2 = input("What is color 2? ")
color3 = input("What is color 3? ")

width, height = t.window_width(), t.window_height()
t.setup(height, width)  # swap window wide and high

t.pensize(24)
t.speed('fastest')  # because I have no patience

for i in range(-30, 33, 3):
    if i % 9 == 0:
        t.color(color1)
    elif i % 9 == 3:
        t.color(color2)
    else:
        t.color(color3)

    t.penup()
    t.goto(i * 10, -260)
    t.pendown()
    zig_zag_line(7)

t.hideturtle()
t.exitonclick()
```

I've included an optional third fix which is to swap the width and height of the window itself.  Since the window might be sized to fit the horizontal drawing, we need to change it to fit the vertical drawing.

Comment: thank you so much :)